# Add Current value to a list then compare with the last value

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose that there is a series of moving numbers:

10, 20, 30, 50, 24, 26, 28

I add the last (current) point which is 28 in my example. to a list

```
List<int> myNumber= new List<int>();
myNumber.Add(currentNumber); //which is 28 in this example
```

Now, this list contains
10, 20, 30, 50, 24, 26, 28 // wherein 28 is the current last value added

Then 30 is added to the list

the output should then be

current value: 30, last number: 30

```
myNumber[myNumber.Count-1];
```

only returns same output
current value: 30 last number in list: 30

the output should be the current value added to the list, and the last number, before the current value added

Comment: Can you provide relatively complete sample code AND expected output for your sample? "the output should then be - current value: 30, last number: 30" - looks like you just want last item in list... Not really clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Index is always start in zero

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int currentNumber = 28;
    List<int> myNumber = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 50, 24, 26 };
    myNumber.Add(currentNumber);
    myNumber.Add(30);

    Console.WriteLine("Last Number: {0}", myNumber[myNumber.Count - 1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Before Last Number {0}", myNumber[myNumber.Count - 2]);
    Console.Read();

    // Output:
    // Last Number: 30
    // Before Last Number: 28
}
```

**Update:** I think this is what your trying to do?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int currentNumber = 28;
    List<int> myNumber = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 50, 24, 26 };

    myNumber.Add(currentNumber);
    Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", myNumber[myNumber.Count - 1]);

    myNumber.Add(30);
    Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", myNumber[myNumber.Count - 1]);
    Console.Read();

    // Output:
    // Number: 28
    // Number: 30
}
```

You can also do `myNumber.Last()` instead of `myNumber[myNumber.Count - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var last = myNumber.Last();
var lastItemIndex = myNumber.FindLastIndex(<predicate function>);
myNumber[lastItemIndex -1 ] =  last number;
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my case since the numbers are constantly added to to the list it takes time to iterate through the list

Comment: Still not getting the last value

Comment: Try the code above. Code a predicate function to match the last.